# ECSlidingViewController, disable rotation iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, autorotate

Been having trouble with autorotation in iOS6, sorted that and now broke the ECSlidingViewController.

In app delegate, I have:

```
slidingViewController.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
```

Then, my rotation methods don't work. So I add:

```
[self.window setRootViewController:myController];
```

And remove the code above, and bam, the rotation methods work, but breaks my ECSlidingViewController, obviously. How can I get to to work together nicely? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should create subclass of `ECSLidingViewController` and implement rotation methods there. So you should use your custom class instead of original (don't forget about storyboard).